# Grails plugin.xml - store in version control?

Tags: grails, version-control, grails-plugin, grails-2.3, plugin.xml

I'm developing a Grails plugin. Should its `plugin.xml` be kept in version control. **Why or why not?**

Because these are just plugin descriptors, I'm not sure if they should always be maintained alongside the rest of the codebase. However perhaps Grails uses them for all sorts of "under the hood" type configurations, in which case they must always be present/consistent with the rest of the app codebase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When in doubt, turn to some of the well maintained plugins out there. I usually look at the [Spring Security Plugin](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core) (I have a fondness for the plugin and Spring Security in general). As you can see from the GitHub for it the plugin.xml is not present. Therefore it's best to follow the same practice and remove it.

Comment: Whenever I have these kind of doubts, I ask myself "what would Burt Beckwith do?" (WWBBD)